# python: taking the return of a function and using it in another function

Tags: python, function, return

Hi guys i got my code to work by putting everything in one function which is this

```
 spam = ''
def enterList (names):   
    newList = []
    while True:
        names = raw_input('list a series of items and press blank when finished: ')
        if names == '':
            break
    newList = newList + [names]

    a = ''
    finalText = ''
    listOfStuff = []
    item = 0
    for i in newList:
        if item < len(newList)-2:
            a = (i + ', ')
            listOfStuff.append(a)
            item +=1
        elif item == len(newList)-2:
            a = (i + ' and ')
            listOfStuff.append(a)
            item +=1
        else:
            a = i
            listOfStuff.append(a)
            break
    finalText = finalText.join(listOfStuff)
    return finalText

print enterList(spam)
```

So the above code works as i want it to. However i was trying to do the same thing by having two separate functions, the issue that i was having was that i couldn't take the return value of one function and use it in the next function.

This is the old code

```
spam = ''

def enterList (names):   
    newList = []
    while True:
        names = raw_input('list a series of items and press blank when finished: ')
        if names == '':
            break
        newList = newList + [names]

    return newList 

print enterList(spam)

def newFunc(Addand):
    a = ''
    finalText = ''
    listOfStuff = []
    item = 0
    for i in spam:
        if item < len(spam)-2:
            a = (i + ', ')
            listOfStuff.append(a)
            item +=1
        elif item == len(spam)-2:
            a = (i + ' and ')
            listOfStuff.append(a)
            item +=1
        else:
            a = i
            listOfStuff.append(a)
            break
    finalText = finalText.join(listOfStuff)
    return finalText


newFunc(spam)

print newFunc (spam)
```

I'm not sure what I was doing wrong doing it this way.
Thanks for any help to get my head around the error with this approach.

Comment: Change `print enterList(spam)` to `spam = enterList(spam)`

Comment: Wow, that solved my issue. Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

In your first function make the return statement

```
return newFunc(newlist)
```

It's not working because the second function is never actually called.

Comment: You're wrong. `return` _works_. Just that the value isn't passed to the next function (I didn't downvote).

Comment: Yeah my bad, I didn't realise the scroll bar so I thought OP was trying to call 2 functions using only 1